# I tried to unload an Application domain but my application stopped working

Tags: c#, wpf, appdomain

I have created a new application domain and load my assembly into it.

```
Assembly assembly = dom.Load("bookOne");
```

Every thing went well. the application used resource dictionary and etc. but when I tried to unload the dll to free memory with this code my application close without any error or warning:

```
try
{
    AppDomain.Unload(dom);
}
catch (CannotUnloadAppDomainException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Book Unloaded!" + " 4");
    AppDomain.Unload(dom);
    GC.Collect();
}
```

The output window shows these after sudden exit:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.AppDomainUnloadedException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.AppDomainUnloadedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll The
>   thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1df8) has exited with code 0
>   (0x0). The thread '' (0xfcc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: did you mean application closes **without** error or warning. what error or warning are you getting in the event logs ?  could you catch the exception and log that to understand why you could not unload. instead of unloading again.in your ctach block

Comment: sorry, output window log was added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A first chance exception of type 'System.AppDomainUnloadedException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

If you are getting AppDomainUnloadedException  ,then you can ignore this because AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown when an Application Domain is unloaded and that is what you want.

From the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainunloadedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to access an
>   unloaded application domain

Comment: This is one of those unexceptional exceptions, like ThreadInterruptedException and such.